# StringInString Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like

I have this database where I have stored some tags in it.
I stored the tags like this:

```
"humor,funny,animal"
```

Now I need a mysql query that selects this line when I search for "humor", "funny" or "animal". What I have until now:

```
SELECT id FROM database WHERE tags REGEXP 'humor' LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Could someone of you please help me out?

*Edit: Thanks for all the responses! I will now need to study this first! But problem solved :)*

Comment: You shouldn't have bunched your tags up into a single string. You should have put them in a table, and instigated a many-to-many relationship between the `tags` table and your `database` (?!) table.

Comment: Uhm, the problem I see in your solution is that I have over 400 tags which I'll use.

Comment: That only strengthens Tomalak's argument. SO has over 29,000 tags and I'd hazard a guess they're stored individually in a `Tags` table

Comment: So, how do you mean 'put them in a table'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LIKE`

```
 SELECT id FROM database WHERE tags LIKE '%humor%' LIMIT 1
```

Which will search for any entry where 'humor' is a substring. Note this will also return items tagged 'humorous'.

But like others said, having a separate table for tags would be best. To do this you will also need a pivot table.

So for example

```
--------------  data  -------------
|     ID         |     NAME       | 
| 1              | example        |
| 2              | example 2      | 
-----------------------------------

--------------  tags  -------------
|      ID        |     NAME       |
| 1              | humor          |
| 2              | cats           |
| 3              | wumpus         |
-----------------------------------

------------  data_tags  ----------
|   DATA_ID      |   TAG_ID       |
| 1              | 1              |
| 1              | 2              |
| 2              | 1              |
| 2              | 3              |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Is "pivot table" the correct name? I thought that was something else. I've always called these things relational entities.

Comment: I've always herd them called 'pivot tables', but I've only been at this for a year. 'relational entities' sounds indicative of a particular abstraction or model.

Comment: "Pivot" means converting columnar to row data - this is more commonly known as a many-to-many relationship, and there's countless names: cross reference, many-to-many, etc...

Comment: @Hans: Using LIKE with wildcards on both sides means 1) an index on the `tags` column can't be used and 2) high possibility of false positives because the string could occur within another word IE: Should "humor" match with "humorous"?

Answer (score 1):

### Short Term

Because the tags are stored as denormalized data, use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('humour', t.tags) > 0
```

### Long Term Solution

Setup the tables to properly handle a many-to-many relationship:

### TAGS

- tag_id (primary key)
- tag_description

### ITEMS

- item_id (primary key)

### ITEM_TAGS

- item_id (primary key, foreign key to ITEMS.item_id)
- tag_id (primary key, foreign key to TAGS.tag_id)

Making the two columns in ITEM_TAGS the primary key means you don't have to worry about duplicates.  And yes, this means using the InnoDB engine...

Then, you can use:

```
SELECT i.item_id
  FROM ITEMS i
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM ITEM_TAGS it
                 JOIN TAGS t ON t.tag_id = it.tag_id
                WHERE t.tag_description = 'humour'
                  AND it.item_id = i.item_id)
```

Comment: Ok, I'll bite... I can't see the `EXISTS` clause performing better than a straight join. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Phil Brown: An INNER JOIN would require adding DISTINCT or GROUP BY to ensure there's only one ITEM record when associated to more than one `TAG`.  It is faster on SQL Server, I haven't had time to test on MySQL but I don't expect it to be worse -- the EXISTS will exit as TRUE on the first match, making it quicker when there's a risk of duplicates.  JOINs are always the fastest answer, and be aware of the implications of using them vs the expected result.

Comment: Also, where's the reference to `i` (`ITEMS`) in your sub-clause?

Comment: Ah, so you're not expecting a unique constraint on `tag_description`?

Comment: @Phil Brown: Right there ;)  Yes, you could add a unique constraint on the tag_description -- you're overcomplicating the example with corner cases.

Comment: @OMGPonies Really? I would have assumed it logical to only have unique entries in `TAGS`. I was even contemplating leaving out the numeric `TAGS.id` at the risk of starting a holy war, though it would make the table itself redundant ;-)

Comment: @Phil Brown: Yes, your questions are leading to a debate about using natural vs artificial/surrogate keys.  If you have a question, post your own.

Comment: @OMGPonies Nope, no further questions. You've explained the `EXISTS` clause in relation to your answer beautifully

Comment: I can't edit it, but the last statement in my response should read: "JOINs are **not** always the fastest answer, and be aware of the implications of using them vs the expected result."

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Tomalak's comment, this would be best solved using a many-to-many relationship for `database` to `tag` relationships. This involves adding two new tables. Something like this (forgive my rusty MySQL)

```
CREATE TABLE `Tag` (
    id  INT(11)     UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tag VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE      (tag)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `DatabaseTag` (
    database_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- just guessing your database.id type here
    tag_id      INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (database_id, tag_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (database_id) REFERENCES `database` (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)      REFERENCES `Tag` (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InndoDB;
```

Then, to find all the `database` records matching tag "humour", your query would look like

```
SELECT id FROM `database` d
INNER JOIN `DatabaseTag` dt ON d.id = dt.database_id
INNER JOIN `Tag` t ON dt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE t.tag = 'humour'
```

Comment: Note: The foreign key relationship to your `database` table will only work if it's using the `InnoDB` engine.